# Get Email notifications when ec2 instance in terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I need to receive notifications whenver my instance in terminated. I know it can be done by cloudtrail and then using sns and sqs to get email for it, if you receive event of termination.

> **Is there a simpler way to do that ?**

Any solution will is appreciated, but I prefer is doing using boto.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to receive a notification directly from Amazon EC2 when an instance is terminated, there are a couple of ways this could be accomplished:

**Auto Scaling** can send a notification when an instance *managed by Auto Scaling* is terminated. See: [Configure Your Auto Scaling Group to Send Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASGettingNotifications.html)

**AWS Config** can also be configured to send a Simple Notification Service (SNS) notification when resources change. This would send *many* notifications, so you would need to inspect and filter the notifications to find the one(s) indicating an instance termination. See the SNS reference in: [Set Up AWS Config Using the Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/gs-console.html) and [Example Amazon SNS Notification and Email from AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-sns-notification.html).

Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) can also push a message to Amazon Queueing Service (SQS), which can be easily polled with the **boto** python SDK.

Receiving notifications via **CloudTrail and CloudWatch Logs** is somewhat messier, so I'd recommend the AWS Config method.

Comment: Update: You can now [use a CloudWatch Events rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48162519/174777).

Answer (score 0):

Now AWS introduced "rules" Under "Events" in AWS CloudWatch. In your case, you can select EC2 as Event Selector and SNS or SQS as Targets.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cloudwatch-events-track-and-respond-to-changes-to-your-aws-resources/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AWS doc: Spot Instance Interruptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html), it is possible to pool the instance-metadata in order to get an approximation of the termination time. You can build any custom monitoring solution around that.

```
> curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/instance-action
{"action": "stop", "time": "2017-09-18T08:22:00Z"}
```

If the instance is not scheduled for termination  a `http:400` will be returned.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a 404?