# create email notification when an ec2 instance is terminated. The Email should contain the instance details.eg:Instance Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I have created cloudwatch alarms for cloudtrail events. I am getting the email notification whenever there is a state change. But It is tough for me to search for the instance which is deleted among hundreds of instances. It will be easier if I get the instance name in the notification Email. Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 3):

The best method is:

- Create an **Amazon SNS topic** to receive the notification
- **Subscribe** to the topic to receive notifications (eg via Email)
- Create a **rule** in Amazon CloudWatch Events to trigger when an instance is terminated:

[image: CloudWatch Events rule]

The result will be a message like this sent via email (or however you subscribed to the topic):

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "0c921724-d932-9cc2-b620-4053a0ad3f73",
    "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2018-01-09T07:04:42Z",
    "region": "ap-southeast-2",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:instance/i-0a32beef35b8da342"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "instance-id": "i-0a32beef35b8da342",
        "state": "terminated"
    }
}
```

Comment: So, there is no need for alarm by doing this way. Whenever an instance is terminated, we will get the notification. Right?

Comment: Is there any way to get instance name in the notification?

Comment: Yes, if you subscribe to the SNS topic as an "Email" subscription, all the information shown above will be sent to the email. This is true for every subscription type.